# mysql replace function not working as expected

Tags: mysql, replace

The following count(*) query returns 4181: -

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kirball_typed WHERE batt = 'III' AND roll LIKE '%/ctr'`

However when I run the following update query, I get "0 rows affected": -

`UPDATE kirball_typed SET roll = REPLACE(roll, '/ctr', ' ') WHERE batt = 'III' AND roll LIKE '%/ctr'`

I expected the update query to simply perform the string replacement if the rows match the where clause, so I expected to see "4181 rows affected"

What's going on here? How do I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Were the 4181 rows actually updated by the command (the "0 rows affected" was a wrong calculation), or not (making the return message coherent?)

Comment: Well the rows were not updated, and thus the "0 rows affected" return message is correct.

Comment: And if you select again now you still get 4181 results?

Comment: Yes the count(*) query still gives 4181 as the result

Comment: can you make a quick sqlfiddle of this?

Comment: The data I have is kind of confidential, not sure if I want to take it to sqlfiddle?

Comment: looks good here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/80041/1 might you have some dirty non-printable characters in your query predicates?